# React-Router (2.6.0) redirection with params outside component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Dear stackoverflowers.

I have updated our project`s dependencies recently. One main updated is migration to the latest react-router. The question is:

How to redirect to named route outside the component with params ? Before we did it like

```
hashHistory.transitionTo(routerName, {params});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you will have do something like this

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/about',
  search: '?the=search',
  state: { some: 'state' }
})
```

Here is the link for [API documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md)
n

Comment: But if my patch contains some named params. For example: <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />  ?  How could I use "push" in this case ?

Comment: the simplest way do that is `history.push(messages/3)`. you can even assign a variable to 3 so that it can change

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my helper function:

```
const _ = require("underscore");
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

module.exports = function (path, params) {
    params = params || [];

    _.each(params, function (paramValue, paramName) {
        path = path.replace(':' + paramName, paramValue);
    }, this);

    browserHistory.push({
        pathname: path,
        state: params
    });
};
```